# Laravel Extended Validation custom message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I wanted to create this extended validation.

```
Validator::extend('my_custom_validation_rule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
   // I guess I should be setting the error message for this here.(Its dynamic)
   // We can return true or false here depending upon our need.  
}
```

I would use this rule like this

`'my_field' => 'required|my_custom_validation_rule'`,

I want to use some dynamic message for the error of "`my_custom_validation_rule`"

I was unable to find something from the documentation about it. Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: Look again: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: I want to provide the message in Validator::extend('my_custom_validation_rule', s closure itself, is it possible ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `extend` method allows to pass the message as a third argument:

```
Validator::extend('my_custom_validation_rule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    // ...
}, 'my custom validation rule message');
```

By default you can only use dynamic variable, which is `:attribute`. If you want to add more use `Validator::replacer()`:

```
Validator::replacer('my_custom_validation_rule', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
    return str_replace(':foo', $parameters[0], $message);
});
```

Comment: Is there any way I can make that message dynamic ? I mean my message varies depending upon the values of $attribute, $value, $parameters - Can I use closure like the second parameter to extend ?

Answer (score 8):

This is basically the same way as @lukasgeiter answer, but in case you need to manage dynamic variable inside the extend function, you can use `$validator->addReplacer` inside the extend directly.

```
Validator::extend('my_custom_validation_rule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    // Test custom message
    $customMessage = request()->get('foo') 
        ? "Foo doesn't exist"
        : "Foo exist";

    // Replace dynamic variable :custom_message with $customMessage
    $validator->addReplacer('my_custom_validation_rule', 
        function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($customMessage) {
            return \str_replace(':custom_message', $customMessage, $message);
        }
    );

    // Test error message. (Make it always fail the validator)
    return false;

}, 'My custom validation rule message. :custom_message');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also define the message for your custom validation rule under validation translations file.

> /resources/lang/en/validation.php

```
....
'unique'                    => 'The :attribute has already been taken.',
'uploaded'                  => 'The :attribute failed to upload.',
'url'                       => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',
//place your translation here
'my_custom_validation_rule' => 'The :attribute value fails custom validation.'
```

Answer (score 1):

possible (not very elegant) workaround is :

```
$message = 'my custom validation rule message' . request()->get('param');
Validator::extend('my_custom_validation_rule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    //
}, $message);
```