# Custom Laravel validation messages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I'm trying to create customized messages for validation in Laravel 5. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$messages = [
    'required'  => 'Harap bagian :attribute di isi.',
    'unique'    => ':attribute sudah digunakan',
];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username' => array('required','unique:Userlogin,username'),
    'password' => 'required',
    'email'    => array('required','unique:Userlogin,email'),$messages
]);

if ($validator->fails()) { 
    return redirect('/')
        ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
        ->withInput();
} else {
    return redirect('/')
        ->with('status', 'Kami sudah mengirimkan email, silahkan di konfirmasi');   
}
```

But it's not working. The message is still the same as the default one. How can I fix this, so that I can use my custom messages?

Comment: All these years and nobody pointed out the simple typo. Inside `Validator::make()`, the `$messages` variable was accidentally put inside the rules array.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you use `$this->validate()` simplest one, then you should write code something like this..

```
$rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required|max:250',
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Comment: With what should i fill the $request var?

Answer (score 125):

**Laravel 5.7.***

Also You can try something like this. For me is the easiest way to make custom messages in methods when you want to validate requests:

```
public function store()
{
    request()->validate([
        'file' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required'
    ],
    [
        'file.required' => 'You have to choose the file!',
        'type.required' => 'You have to choose type of the file!'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This was the easiest for me as I was pressed for time and needed to do this in only one place. It is quite handy but if you are going to need custom messages in a number of places, it would be more prudent to have them all in one place. It makes tracking easier and makes the code more legible than if you have custom messages in each validation statement. I upvoted your answer because of my unique usecase and I want to say thank you for it (even though, SO advises against thanks and me too posts, you need to know that you helped me out of a bind and I delivered in time).

Comment: Thank You so much @Mexen Im glad that I could help!

Comment: @Geo4you Thanks a lot, it really helped me.

Answer (score 33):

**For Laravel** **8.x**, **7.x**, **6.x** 
With the custom rule defined, you might use it in your controller validation like so :

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
       'f_name' => 'required|min:8',
       'l_name' => 'required',
   ],
   [
    'f_name.required'=> 'Your First Name is Required', // custom message
    'f_name.min'=> 'First Name Should be Minimum of 8 Character', // custom message
    'l_name.required'=> 'Your Last Name is Required' // custom message
   ]
);
```

For localization you can use :

```
['f_name.required'=> trans('user.your first name is required'],
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is fantastic. I missed this in the docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

You can provide custom message like :

```
$rules = array(
            'URL' => 'required|url'
        );    
$messages = array(
                'URL.required' => 'URL is required.'
            );
$validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules, $messages );

if ( $validator->fails() ) 
{
    return [
        'success' => 0, 
        'message' => $validator->errors()->first()
    ];
}
```

or

The way you have tried, you missed `Validator::replacer()`, to replace the `:variable`

```
Validator::replacer('custom_validation_rule', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
    return str_replace(':foo', $parameters[0], $message);
});
```

You can read more from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/extending-validation-with-custom-message-attribute?page=1) and replacer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025252/laravel-extended-validation-custom-message)

Comment: any example how to use it ?

Comment: added example for first method.

Answer (score 12):

```
$rules = [
  'username' => 'required,unique:Userlogin,username',
  'password' => 'required',
  'email'    => 'required,unique:Userlogin,email'
];

$messages = [
  'required'  => 'The :attribute field is required.',
  'unique'    => ':attribute is already used'
];

$request->validate($rules,$messages);
//only if validation success code below will be executed
```

Comment: This is the same as [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53573460/1255289) posted a year ago.

Answer (score 7):

```
//Here is the shortest way of doing it.
 $request->validate([
     'username' => 'required|unique:Userlogin,username',
     'password' => 'required',
     'email'    => 'required|unique:Userlogin,email'
 ],
 [
     'required'  => 'The :attribute field is required.',
     'unique'    => ':attribute is already used'
 ]);
//The code below will be executed only if validation is correct.
```

Answer (score 7):

run below command to create a custom rule on Laravel

ı assuming that name is CustomRule

```
php artisan make:rule CustomRule
```

and as a result, the command was created such as PHP code

> **if required keyword hasn't on Rules,That rule will not work**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CustomRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //return  true or false
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

and came time using that
first, we should create a request class if we have not

```
php artisan make:request CustomRequest
```

**CustomRequest.php**

```php
<?php


namespace App\Http\Requests\Payment;

use App\Rules\CustomRule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{


    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'custom' => ['required', new CustomRule()],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function messages(): array
    {
        return [
            'custom.required' => ':attribute can not be empty.',
        ];
    }
}
```

and on your controller, you should inject custom requests to the controller

your controller method

```
class FooController
{
    public function bar(CustomRequest $request)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In the case you are using Request as a separate file:

```
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        'preparation_method' => 'required|string',
    ];
 }

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'preparation_method.required' => 'Description is required',
    ];
}
```

Tested out in Laravel 6+

Answer (score 5):

For those who didn't get this issue resolve (tested on Laravel 8.x):

```
$validated = Validator::make($request->all(),[
   'code' => 'required|numeric'
  ],
  [
    'code.required'=> 'Code is Required', // custom message
    'code.numeric'=> 'Code must be Number', // custom message       
   ]
);

//Check the validation
if ($validated->fails())
{        
    return $validated->errors();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required|max:250',
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
        'max' => 'The :attribute field is may not be greater than :max.'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the methods `setAttributeNames()` and `setCustomMessages()`,
like this:

```
$validation = Validator::make($this->input, static::$rules);

$attributeNames = array(
    'email' => 'E-mail',
    'password' => 'Password'
);

$messages = [
    'email.exists' => 'No user was found with this e-mail address'
];

$validation->setAttributeNames($attributeNames);
$validation->setCustomMessages($messages);
```

Comment: I really like this method. It's great when used with an after hook on a FormRequest, eg. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 10.x**

If you are using Form Requests, add another method called `messages(): array` in your request.

```
class YourRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            ...
        ];
    }

    //Add the following method

    public function messages(): array
    {
        return [
            'email.required' => 'Custom message for Email Required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Then the message will be displayed automatically once the request is send from the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can customise the message for different scenarios based on the request.

Just return a different message with a conditional.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Helpers\QueryBuilderHelper;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ProductIsUnique implements Rule
{

    private array $attributes;
    private bool $hasAttributes;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
        $this->hasAttributes = true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $brandAttributeOptions = collect($this->attributes['relationships']['brand-attribute-options']['data'])->pluck('id');

        $query = Product::query();

        $query->when($brandAttributeOptions->isEmpty(), function ($query) use ($value) {
            $query->where('name', $value);
            $this->hasAttributes = false;
        });

        
        return !$query->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return ($this->hasAttributes) ? 'The Selected attributes & Product Name are not unique' : 'Product Name is not unique';
    }
}
```