# Laravel : Validation messages for custom rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add a custom validation message using the below code,

```
$validator = Validator::make(
            $user,
            [
                'first_name' => 'required|min:2',
                'email'      => [
                    'required',
                    'email',
                    Rule::notIn(array_column(Customer::getEmails(), 'email'))
                ]
            ],
            ['email.required' => 'Email is required (Custom message)']);
```

I have added a custom message for `email required` validation. No issues there.

For `Rule::notIn` validation, currently it is returning `The email is invalid`. How can I add a custom message in this case?

Unable to find anything related in Laravel docs about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom message laravel Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007905/custom-message-laravel-validation)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile This is a whole different case. Please read it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
        $user,
        [
            'first_name' => 'required|min:2',
            'email'      => [
                'required',
                'email',
                Rule::notIn(array_column(Customer::getEmails(), 'email'))
            ]
        ],
        [
            'email.required' => 'Email is required (Custom message)',
            'email.email' => 'Your custom message here',
            'email.not_in' => 'Your custom message here',
        ]
);
```