# Validating Password rules with a custom error message

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-validation, laravel-localization

Using standard notation like "password.required" I can customize an error message for built-in validation rules. But how can I customize error messages for `Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password` rules?

```
$rules = [
    'password' => [
        'required',
        'confirmed',
        Rules\Password::min(8)->letters()->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols(),
    ],
];
$messages = [
    'password.required'  => 'يجب ادخال كلمة المرور',
    'password.confirmed' => 'كلمة المرور غير متطابقة',
];
$request->validate($rules, $messages);
```

How to customize the messages for `min()`, `letters()`, etc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Laravel validation messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007905/custom-laravel-validation-messages)

Comment: no because im using Rules\Password, I know how to customize the default validate but the Rules I don't

Comment: I don't think it possible aside from duplicating/extending the Class or overriding the strings via Translations,.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/36960#issuecomment-827895179) in the original pull request, you can't do this in code, and have to use the JSON localization files.

So check [the validation class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Password.php#L269) for the default text and then in `resources/lang/ar.json` add a translation for it, like so:

```json
{
  "The :attribute must contain at least one letter.": ":attribute يجب أن يحتوي على الأقل حرف واحد.",
  "The :attribute must contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter.": ":attribute يجب أن يحتوي على الأقل حرف كبير واحد وحرف صغير واحد.",
  "The :attribute must contain at least one number.": ":attribute يجب أن يحتوي على الأقل رقم واحد.",
  "The :attribute must contain at least one symbol.": ":attribute يجب أن يحتوي على الأقل رمز واحد."  
}
```

The length message uses the standard one found in `resources/lang/ar/validation.php`:

```php
<?php
return [
  "min" => [
    "string" => "يجب أن يكون طول نص حقل :attribute على الأقل :min حروفٍ/حرفًا.",
  ],
];
```

Or it can be declared in your code above.

```php
$messages = [
    'password.required'  => 'يجب ادخال كلمة المرور',
    'password.confirmed' => 'كلمة المرور غير متطابقة',
    'password.min' => 'whatever',
];
```

Note there are packages such as [Laravel Lang](https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang) that can do all these translations for you.