# Laravel, use only custom rule class for validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have some dynamic fields and can't use usual field validation. My question is, how can I use only my custom rule class without defining if it's required or not?

This doesn't work:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'social_links.fb' => new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataFb),
            'social_links.linkedin' => new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataLinkedIn),
            'social_links.twitter' => new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataTwitter)
        ]);
```

To get this work I need to add something like:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'social_links.fb' => ['sometimes', new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataFb)],
            'social_links.linkedin' => ['sometimes', new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataLinkedIn)],
            'social_links.twitter' => ['sometimes', new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataTwitter)]
        ]);
```

To use always validation class I need to set `required` or `sometimes` but I would need only to use validation class without other definitions, is that possible?

Comment: Try to put your custom rule validation in array like this: `'social_links.fb' => [new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataFb)]`

Comment: So it works but only if I put already content there but I need to get there also if content is missing, means null

Comment: Solved, you should place "required" and in 3th paramter of $this->validate() place custom message string, more info at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007905/custom-laravel-validation-messages#answer-62172386

Comment: Show us your `app\Rules\SocialFieldValidation.php` class logic/source code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in your comment, if putting your custom rule validation in array works but you want this working in case of null value, then you need to do use the `nullable` validation:

```
$this->validate($request, [
     'social_links.fb' => ['nullable', new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataFb)],
     'social_links.linkedin' => ['nullable', new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataLinkedIn)],
     'social_links.twitter' => ['nullable', new SocialFieldValidation($fieldDataTwitter)]
]);
```

If you need the documentation:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields