# Laravel Validate ->validate() method removed custom added errors?

Tags: laravel, validation, custom-errors

I'm trying to use the Laravel validator to include some custom error messages before I run the validate() method. However it appears that running this method then removed any previously added errors.

I can confirm that the error message appears when I dump out the validator messages before hitting validate()

```
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $this->data,
        $this->rules
    );

    $validator->errors()->add('meal', 'The meal field is required.');

    $validator->validate();
```

How I can validate my data but still include the error relating to the meal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Laravel validation messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007905/custom-laravel-validation-messages)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunetly that isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to use is the after [validation hook](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#after-validation-hook). This will allow you to add more errors like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    $this->data, 
    $this->rules
);

$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    $validator->errors()->add(
        'field', 'Something is wrong with this field!'
    );
});
 
$validator->validate();
```