# Laravel default validation message not working

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-10, laravel-validation, validationerror

The default validation error message in Laravel is not functioning as expected. When using validation, the response displays a generic message like ***(validation.required)*** instead of the intended **validation message.**

validation code :

```
    $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

response:

```
lluminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object ( [bags:protected] => Array ( [default] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object ( [messages:protected] => Array ( [email] => Array ( [0] => validation.required ) [password] => Array ( [0] => validation.required ) ) [format:protected] => :message ) ) )
```

I want :
[email] => Array ( [0] => email field is required ) but it response [email] => Array ( [0] => validation.required )

---

I've implemented this type of validation before, and it used to work. However, unexpectedly, it has started exhibiting this issue. It's becoming time-consuming to address doing this

```
 $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ],[
'email.required' => 'message',
]);
```

I need solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007905/custom-laravel-validation-messages